# Changing this to a slide function jQuery

Tags: jquery

I dont know much about Javascript and im trying to change this show element script into a nicer slideToggle() motion instead of just popping up.

Currently it reveals hidden elements. The element revealed is dependent upon what id is selected in a html select list.

Here is the JS:

```
$('#business_type').change(function(){
        $("#common >div").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("style", "display: none;");
        })
        $("#" + $(this).val()).attr("style", "display: block;");
        })
```

Is there a function i can add to it just to toggle between hidden elements in a slide motion.

Answer (score 1):

Try the jQuery **show(*[duration]*)** function. In your case, considering the `$("#common >div")` elements are already hidden, you could try

```
$("#common >div").each(function(index, elem) {
    $(elem).show(500);
});
```

If not already hidden, you can try `$(selector).hide().show(/*duration*/)`

Comment: cant seem to adopt it to this code. I'm unfamiliar with jQuery

Comment: [Here](http://api.jquery.com/show/)'s the documentation. The implementation should be like

`$('#business_type').change(function () {
    $("#common >div").each(function (index, elem) {
        $(elem).show(500);
    })
});`